# List of all Teams on a Sharepoint Online page

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want my users to be able to see a list of all the Teams that are available in my organisation. (Right now I'm not particularly bothered whether this means only public Teams or if it should include the names of private Teams.)

One obvious place, which is outside Sharepoint, is in the Teams application, under the Teams section, and through "[Join or create a team](https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/discover)". Unfortunately the list of Teams presented to users here is built via Microsoft Graph and only shows a subset of the available Teams. (Apparently this is by design, and it is the list of Teams that Graph considers to be "interesting" to the user.) Frustratingly, the adjacent [⚙](https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/manageteams/myteams/) links to the list of Teams of which I am already a member, but there's nowhere that links to *all Teams*.

My aim is to see if I can create a page that lists the available Teams, preferably linked by URL, from which users can select relevant entries.

I can do this manually, but I would prefer to automate the process as updating such a list by hand would be tedious and error-prone. I can find [powershell code](https://mymicrosoftexchange.wordpress.com/2019/07/23/microsoft-teams-powershell-a-simple-use-case-to-get-you-started/) to list the Teams sites, but nothing I understand on if and how this could be added into Sharepoint Online.

Is this even possible? (And if so, how?)